# How to get all users with edit permission in Google Drive API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm working on Google Drive app script and using the Advanced Drive Service.
And I want to get all users have edit permission of a file, is there any method like `File.getEditors()` of the build-in service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Permissions.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/list) endpoint.